# subdomain VHost setup with EC2/Route53

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-route53

I'm currently trying to set up a new subdomain via route53 and ec2, but receiving timeout errors whenever I try to access it via my browser. Amazon security group is set up to allow all traffic over port 80.

I wrote the follow vhosts file and stored it under sites-available as "new.mysite.com.conf" :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName new.mysite.com
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/newmysite
        <Directory /var/www/newmysite>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled this running;

```
a2ensite new.mysite.com.conf
service apache2 reload
```

Lastly, under route53, I set up a new A Record, set to non-alias, and pointing to the public IP of the EC2 server as listed under my running instances.

I've ensured that a test page is available under var/www/newmysite/index.php , alongside creating a backup var/www/newmysite/index.html for access.

The subdomain itself just gives a timeout. Hitting the server's public IP directly gives the default apache2 "it works!" page.

Would anyone have any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please share what domain name you have specified in the A record that you say you have set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a redirect rule from HTTP to HTTPS

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I guess when you hit `new.mysite.com` it redirects to HTTPs `https://new.mysite.com` since there is no SSL-enabled VirtualHost(443) and no listener on 443 the connection is refused.

Try disabling the redirect rule or you can try using a Self-signed certificate or configure an ELB to use ACM Certificate and the point the Route53 Domain to ELB.

```
curl -v -L http://new.mysite.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://new.mysite.com/
*   Trying 10.116.131.69...
* Connected to new.mysite.com (10.116.131.69) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: new.mysite.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://new.mysite.com/'
* Found bundle for host new.mysite.com: 0x7ff7a3c0fbc0
*   Trying 10.116.131.69...
* connect to 10.116.131.69 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to new.mysite.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to new.mysite.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like mentioned in the previous answer, there's an SSL redirect. SSL uses port `443` which isn't exposed in your security group.

1. Modify the security group to allow all traffic over port `443`. This enables access to the website over `https`
2. [Install and configure SSL certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) for the domain. You can install a free certificate from Let's Encrypt. Follow the steps below:

   - Install Certbot, a bot that automatically updates your certificate before it's 90-day expiration period

     - `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot`
     - `$ sudo apt-get update`
     - `sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache`
   - Configure a new certficate for your subdomain

     - `sudo certbot --apache -d new.mysite.com`

Now your site should be up and running on https.

ps. while writing this answer I noticed you had turned off the `http` redirect `https` you might want to turn this back on after enabling https on the website. This ensures all communication to your website are secure.